# SyncFrameworkToolkit + SqlServerCE + Entity Framework Example

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework, sql-server-ce-4

I'm looking for a very simple example of SyncFrameworkToolkit with a SQL Server CE local database synchronizing with the templated web service and provisioned remote sql server. Seems like a rather simple concept but after days of searching I can not find an example. I was able to see SQLite examples but i would rather use SQL Server CE with entity framework.

I have a requirement that all database calls must go through a web-service so I must use the web-service that comes with the toolkit and not  synchronization framework 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the Sync Framework Toolkit for that (although the toolkit actually contains a sample SQL CE provider to be used with Sync Toolkit).

you can easily sync SQL CE and SQL Server via WCF. this sample shows you exactly how to do that: [SQL Server and SQL Compact N-Tier with WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-SQL-Server-7e88adab)